# iOS E-mail stuck in « All Inboxes »

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, email

In the iOS Mail app, there are 5 emails in the "All Inboxes" section. Those 4 emails are NOT in any other inboxes.

So I tried deleting them and ... they keep coming back!

Even stranger, the 4 emails ONLY appear in "All Inboxes", they don't appear in any of the sub-account inboxes.

So, I disabled "Mail" in my outlook account. They're still here! I no longer have a "outlook" sub-account, but those 4 emails are still in All Inboxes. I tried to quit the app a few times, restart the phone. Still here...

When I tap on one of those messages, I get a black screen (dark mode) Or gray empty screen, no errors.

I completely deleted the account in settings but they are still there!! Any tips?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS emails stuck in All Inboxes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374000/ios-emails-stuck-in-all-inboxes)

Comment: The text of your question seems to be mostly cut and pasted from the question referenced in WGroleau's comment above.

Comment: Hi @IconDaemon! Yes, it's pretty much a copy paste because it's almost the same thing. The difference is that he was able to resolve the issue by removing the account.. On my side, even when completely removing the account, the emails are still there!! So the question is still valid and I am still seeking for help!

Comment: @WGroleau: Unfortunately no. Same issue but unable to fix the issue based on the answer in that thread.